# Mathematical expression evaluator (C++) Using Flex and Yacc

Tags: c++, math-expression-eval, yacc, flex

Based on this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/280061/507), I thought I should show how to implement an expression evaluator using Flex and Bison.

Updated: [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280095/mathematical-expression-evaluator-c-using-flex-and-yacc-attempt2)

Currently it does not handle releasing the expressions (I only spent an hour throwing it together).

#### Makefile

```
YACC            ?= bison
LEX             ?= flex
CXX             ?= g++

SRC             = exp.tab.cpp exp.lex.cpp Lexer.cpp Parser.cpp Expression.cpp main.cpp
OBJ             = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))

expression: $(OBJ)
    g++ -std=c++17 -o $@ $^

%.tab.cpp: %.y
    $(YACC) -o $@ -d $<

%.lex.cpp: %.l
    $(LEX) -t --c++ --header-file=$*.lex.h $< > $@

%.o:    %.cpp
    $(CXX) -std=c++17 -c $*.cpp
```

#### exp.l

```
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%option yyclass="Lexer"

%{

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int Lexer::yylexWithAction()
#define IN_LEXER
#include "exp.tab.hpp"

%}

IdentifierObject    [a-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*
LiteralInteger      ([1-9][0-9]*)|(0)

WhiteSpace          [ \t\r]+
NewLine             \n


%%
\(                  {return '(';}
\)                  {return ')';}
\^                  {return '^';}
\+                  {return '+';}
\-                  {return '-';}
\*                  {return '*';}
\/                  {return '/';}
\=                  {return '=';}


{LiteralInteger}    {return yy::Parser::token::LITERAL_INTEGER;}
{IdentifierObject}  {return yy::Parser::token::IDENTIFIER_OBJECT;}

{WhiteSpace}        {/* Ignore */}
{NewLine}           {return '\n';}
.                   {throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Character");}

%%
```

#### exp.y

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require "2.1a"
%defines
%define "parser_class_name" "Parser"

%{

#include "Lexer.h"
#include "Expression.h"

using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Lexer;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Expression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::PowerExpression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::AddExpression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::SubExpression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::MulExpression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::DivExpression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::LiteralIntExpression;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::IdentifierExpression;


//namespace ThorsAnvial::Anvil::Ice {
int yylex(void*, ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Lexer& lexer);
//}


%}


%parse-param {Lexer&        lexer}
%lex-param   {Lexer&        lexer}

%token                          IDENTIFIER_OBJECT
%token                          LITERAL_INTEGER
%type   <expression>            Expression
%type   <expression>            PowerExpression
%type   <expression>            AddExpression
%type   <expression>            MultExpression
%type   <expression>            PrimaryExpression
%type   <expression>            Literal
%type   <identifier>            Identifier

%union {
    Expression*                 expression;
    IdentifierExpression*       identifier;
};



%%

StatementList:          Statement
                    |   StatementList '\n' Statement

Statement:              Expression                                          {/*Empty*/}
                    |   Identifier '=' Expression                           {IdentifierExpression::addValue($1, $3);}

Expression:             PowerExpression                                     {$$ = $1;std::cerr << "Value: " << $1->evaluate() << "\n";}

PowerExpression:        AddExpression                                       {$$ = $1;}
                    |   PowerExpression '^' AddExpression                   {$$ = new PowerExpression($1, $3);}

AddExpression:          MultExpression                                      {$$ = $1;}
                    |   AddExpression '+' MultExpression                    {$$ = new AddExpression($1, $3);}
                    |   AddExpression '-' MultExpression                    {$$ = new SubExpression($1, $3);}

MultExpression:         PrimaryExpression                                   {$$ = $1;}
                    |   MultExpression '*' PrimaryExpression                {$$ = new MulExpression($1, $3);}
                    |   MultExpression '/' PrimaryExpression                {$$ = new DivExpression($1, $3);}

PrimaryExpression:      Literal                                             {$$ = $1;}
                    |   '(' Expression ')'                                  {$$ = $2;}
                    |   Identifier                                          {$$ = $1;}

Literal:                LITERAL_INTEGER                                     {$$ = new LiteralIntExpression(lexer.lexem());}

Identifier:             IDENTIFIER_OBJECT                                   {$$ = new IdentifierExpression(lexer.lexem());}

%%


int yylex(void*, Lexer& lexer)
{
    return lexer.yylexWithActionGo();
}

void yy::Parser::error(yy::location const& /*location*/, std::string const& msg)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(msg);
}
```

#### Lexer.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_LEXER_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_LEXER_H

#ifndef IN_LEXER
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#endif

#include <string_view>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Lexer: public yyFlexLexer
{
    bool started;
    public:
        Lexer(std::istream& input = std::cin, std::ostream& output = std::cerr);
        std::string_view lexem() const;
        virtual int yylex() override {throw std::runtime_error("Wrong Lex Called");}
        virtual int yylexWithAction();
        int yylexWithActionGo() { started = true; return yylexWithAction(); }
};

}

#endif
```

#### Lexer.cpp

```
#include "Lexer.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice;

Lexer::Lexer(std::istream& input, std::ostream& output)
    : yyFlexLexer(&input, &output)
    , started(false)
{}

std::string_view Lexer::lexem() const
{
    int length = started ? YYLeng() : 0;
    std::string_view    tokenView(YYText(), length);
    while (tokenView.size() > 0 && tokenView[tokenView.size() - 1] == '\0')
    {
        tokenView.remove_suffix(1);
    }
    return tokenView;
}
```

#### Parser.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_PARSER_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_PARSER_H

#include "exp.tab.hpp"
#include "Expression.h"

namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Lexer;
class Parser
{
    public:
        Parser(Lexer& lexer);
        bool parse();
    private:
        Lexer&          lexer;
        ::yy::Parser    parser;
};

}

#endif
```

#### Parser.cpp

```
#include "Parser.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice;

Parser::Parser(Lexer& lexer)
    : lexer(lexer)
    , parser(lexer)
    , result(result)
{}

bool Parser::parse()
{
    return parser.parse() == 0;
}
```

#### Expression.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_EXPRESSION_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_EXPRESSION_H

#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <charconv>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Expression
{
    public:
        virtual ~Expression(){}
        virtual int evaluate() const = 0;
};
class BinaryExpression: public Expression
{
    Expression* lhs;
    Expression* rhs;
    public:
        BinaryExpression(Expression* lhs, Expression* rhs)
            : lhs(lhs)
            , rhs(rhs)
        {}
        int le() const {return lhs->evaluate();}
        int re() const {return rhs->evaluate();}
};

class PowerExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const { return std::pow(le(), re());}
};
class AddExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() + re();}
};
class SubExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() - re();}
};
class MulExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() * re();}
};
class DivExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() / re();}
};
class LiteralIntExpression: public Expression
{
    int value;
    public:
        LiteralIntExpression(std::string_view view)
            : value(0)
        {
            std::from_chars(std::begin(view), std::end(view), value);
        }
        virtual int evaluate() const {return value;}
};
class IdentifierExpression: public Expression
{
    static std::map<std::string, int>   valueMap;

    std::string identifier;
    public:
        IdentifierExpression(std::string_view view)
            : identifier(view)
        {}
        virtual int evaluate() const {return valueMap[identifier];}

        static void addValue(IdentifierExpression* exp, Expression* value)
        {
            valueMap[exp->identifier] = value->evaluate();
        }
};

}

#endif
```

#### Expression.cpp

```
#include "Expression.h"

std::map<std::string, int>   ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::IdentifierExpression::valueMap;
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "Lexer.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Expression.h"

int main()
{
    using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Lexer;
    using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Parser;
    using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Expression;

    Lexer       lexer(std::cin, std::cout);
    Parser      parser(lexer);

    try {
        parser.parse();
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it handle releasing memory pretty much automatically if you changed the raw pointers to `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @DanielSchepler The trouble is that flex/yacc are not designed for advanced C++. They do not incorporate the move semantics required for unique_ptrs.

Comment: OK - in a situation like that, personally, I'd probably treat the Bison/Yacc infrastructure like a C (or legacy C++) API, and try to push `uniqueptr.release()` and `capture(rawptr)` as close to the boundary with that API as possible.  Where `template<typename T> std::unique_ptr<T> capture(T* rawptr) { return { rawptr }; }` is a common template I like to use to signal where my code is taking ownership of a pointer from the C API.  (Though at this point, I might be dangerously close to something that should be put in an answer instead of a comment...)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I have an update that handles the pointers: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280095/mathematical-expression-evaluator-c-using-flex-and-yacc-attempt2

Answer (score 5):

## The Makefile can be improved a bit

The Makefile looks very reasonable, but there are a few things that can be improved:

- Use `$(CXX)` instead of `g++` for `expression`, just like you did for `%.o`.
- It's great that you don't hardcode which binaries to use, but it's also common to use `$(CXXFLAGS)` and `$(LDFLAGS)` when compiling, and if `$(CXXFLAGS)` is not defined, set it to something like `-O2 -Wall -g`.
- `patsubst` is a GNU make extension, you can avoid that by removing `SRC` and just defining: `OBJ = exp.tab.o exp.lex.o Lexer.o ...`
- Add a `clean` rule and a corresponding `.PHONY: clean`.

## Incorrect precedence for powers

From your grammer it seems that the power operator has a lower precedence than addition and subtraction, which is [wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Definition).

## Consider creating custom exceptions

Just like the in the code in the [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280061/mathematical-expression-evaluator-c) you linked to, create custom exception classes that derive from `std::runtime_error`. This conveys extra information to the caller, and allows them to programmatically make a distinction between different parser errors without having to parse the `what()` text.

## Check the return value of `std::from_chars()`

You are ignoring the return value of `std::from_chars()`. While `LiteralIntExpressions` is only called with a string that matches the `LiteralInteger` lexer rule, it is still possible that the provided number is out of the range of an `int`.

## Check that identifiers exist when evaluating an expression

In `IdentifierExpression::evaluate()`, you don't check if a given identifier exists in `valueMap` first. You probably want to do that first and throw an exception if it doesn't exist, otherwise the program will continue but will return unexpected results.

## Output never goes to `output`

While the constructor of `Lexer` takes a `std::ostream` reference that is supposed to be where the output is written to, you hardcoded the output to `std::cerr` in exp.y.

I also find it strange that you use `std::cerr` as the default output stream, it should just be `std::cout`.

## Tie it all together

The code looks very clean, but in your example `main()` function you have to write a lot of lines just to parse the input. It would be nice if you can create a single function or class that takes care of setting up the `Lexer` and `Parser` objects. Ideally, just:

```
#include "ExpressionParser.h"

int main() {
    ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::ExpressionParser::parse(std::cin, std::cout);
}
```

Comment: `otherwise the program will continue but will return unexpected results`: It will continue with using the value `0`. But point taken.

Comment: All good points. Thanks. It just re-enforces one of my rules I broke. Unit test your results. Should have noticed that I got the pow precedence wrong.