# Mathematical expression evaluator (C++) Using Flex and Yacc Attempt2

Tags: c++, makefile, yacc, flex

Attempt 2: First Try [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/280086/507).

Usage:

```
./expression
```

Then you can either type expressions that are evaluated when you hit `<enter>`.

```
10 + 2 ^ 2
Value = 40
```

Or you can assign value to variables:

```
data = 10 + 14 / 2
data + 1
Value = 18
```

Note: It is a feature of the language that all variables are always valid. By default they are all 0 unless you explicitly assign a value.

This times I have generalized the "Action" part of the parser. Thus each rule match will call a virtual function in the "Action" object.

I have provided an example implation of an "Action" object that simply prints expression and stores values into variables. But also handles all the memory management needs so that we don't leak expression even if there is an exception.

Also simple error handling is done. If a syntax error happens then we skip to the end of the line and then try to start again.

### The Generic Expression Part

#### Makefile

```
YACC            ?= bison
LEX             ?= flex
CXX             = g++
CXXFLAGS        += -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter
LEXFLAGS        += -t --c++

SRC             = exp.tab.cpp exp.lex.cpp Lexer.cpp Parser.cpp Expression.cpp main.cpp
OBJ             = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))

expression: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.PHONEY:    clean

clean:
    $(RM) -f $(OBJ) exp.tab.cpp exp.tab.h exp.lex.cpp exp.lex.h location.hh  position.hh stack.hh

%.tab.cpp: %.y
    $(YACC) -o $@ -d $<

%.lex.cpp: %.l
    $(LEX) $(LEXFLAGS) --header-file=$*.lex.h $< > $@

exp.tab.o:  CXXFLAGS += -Wno-uninitialized-const-reference
exp.lex.o:  CXXFLAGS += -Wno-sign-compare
%.o:    %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $*.cpp
```

#### exp.l

```
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%option yyclass="Lexer"

%{

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int Lexer::yylexWithAction()
#define IN_LEXER
#include "exp.tab.hpp"

%}

IdentifierObject    [a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*
LiteralInteger      ([1-9][0-9]*)|(0)

WhiteSpace          [ \t\r]+
NewLine             \n


%%
\(                  {return '(';}
\)                  {return ')';}
\^                  {return '^';}
\+                  {return '+';}
\-                  {return '-';}
\*                  {return '*';}
\/                  {return '/';}
\=                  {return '=';}


{LiteralInteger}    {return yy::Parser::token::LITERAL_INTEGER;}
{IdentifierObject}  {return yy::Parser::token::IDENTIFIER_OBJECT;}

{WhiteSpace}        {/* Ignore */}
{NewLine}           {return '\n';}
<<EOF>>             {return yy::Parser::token::END_OF_FILE;}
.                   {throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Character");}

%%
```

#### exp.y

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require "2.1a"
%defines
%define "parser_class_name" "Parser"

%{

#include "Lexer.h"
#include "Action.h"

using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Lexer;
using ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Action;

//namespace ThorsAnvial::Anvil::Ice {
int yylex(void*, ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Lexer& lexer);
//}

#define YYSTYPE Action::Id

%}


%parse-param {Lexer&        lexer}
%parse-param {Action&       action}
%lex-param   {Lexer&        lexer}

%token                          IDENTIFIER_OBJECT
%token                          LITERAL_INTEGER
%token                          END_OF_FILE



%%

Program:                StatementList                                       {action.program($1);return 0;}

StatementList:          END_OF_FILE                                         {$$ = action.statementListCreate();}
                    |   Statement                                           {$$ = action.statementListCreate();action.statementListAdd($$, $1);}
                    |   StatementList Statement                             {$$ = action.statementListAdd($1, $2);}

Statement:              Expression '\n'                                     {$$ = action.statementExpression($1);}
                    |   Identifier '=' Expression '\n'                      {$$ = action.statementAssignment($1, $3);}

Expression:             AddExpression                                       {$$ = action.expression($1);}

AddExpression:          MultExpression                                      {$$ = action.addExpression($1);}
                    |   AddExpression '+' MultExpression                    {$$ = action.addExpressionAdd($1, $3);}
                    |   AddExpression '-' MultExpression                    {$$ = action.addExpressionSub($1, $3);}

MultExpression:         PowerExpression                                     {$$ = action.multExpression($1);}
                    |   MultExpression '*' PowerExpression                  {$$ = action.multExpressionMul($1, $3);}
                    |   MultExpression '/' PowerExpression                  {$$ = action.multExpressionDiv($1, $3);}

PowerExpression:        PrimaryExpression                                   {$$ = action.powerExpression($1);}
                    |   PowerExpression '^' PrimaryExpression               {$$ = action.powerExpressionPow($1, $3);}

PrimaryExpression:      Literal                                             {$$ = action.primaryExpressionLiteral($1);}
                    |   '(' Expression ')'                                  {$$ = action.primaryExpressionSubExpr($2);}
                    |   Identifier                                          {$$ = action.primaryExpressionIdent($1);}

Literal:                LITERAL_INTEGER                                     {$$ = action.literalCreate(lexer.lexem());}

Identifier:             IDENTIFIER_OBJECT                                   {$$ = action.identifierCreate(lexer.lexem());}


%%


int yylex(void*, Lexer& lexer)
{
    return lexer.yylexWithActionGo();
}

void yy::Parser::error(yy::location const& /*location*/, std::string const& msg)
{
    action.handleError(msg);
}
```

#### Action.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_ACTION_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_ACTION_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Action
{
    public:
        using Id = std::size_t;

        virtual ~Action()   {}

        virtual void program(Id StatementList)                                      = 0;

        virtual Id  statementListCreate()                                           = 0;
        virtual Id  statementListAdd(Id statementList, Id statement)                = 0;

        virtual Id  statementExpression(Id expression)                              = 0;
        virtual Id  statementAssignment(Id identifier, Id expression)               = 0;

        virtual Id  expression(Id addExpression)                                    = 0;

        virtual Id  addExpression(Id multExpression)                                = 0;
        virtual Id  addExpressionAdd(Id addExpression, Id multExpression)           = 0;
        virtual Id  addExpressionSub(Id addExpression, Id multExpression)           = 0;

        virtual Id  multExpression(Id powerExpression)                              = 0;
        virtual Id  multExpressionMul(Id multExpression, Id powerExpression)        = 0;
        virtual Id  multExpressionDiv(Id multExpression, Id powerExpression)        = 0;

        virtual Id powerExpression(Id primaryExpression)                            = 0;
        virtual Id powerExpressionPow(Id powerExpression, Id primaryExpression)     = 0;

        virtual Id primaryExpressionLiteral(Id literal)                             = 0;
        virtual Id primaryExpressionSubExpr(Id expression)                          = 0;
        virtual Id primaryExpressionIdent(Id identifier)                            = 0;

        virtual Id literalCreate(std::string_view literal)                          = 0;
        virtual Id identifierCreate(std::string_view identifier)                    = 0;

        virtual void handleError(std::string const& msg)                            = 0;

        virtual void clean()                                                        = 0;
};

}

#endif
```

#### Lexer.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_LEXER_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_LEXER_H

#ifndef IN_LEXER
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#endif

#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Lexer: public yyFlexLexer
{
    bool started;
    public:
        Lexer(std::istream& input = std::cin);
        std::string_view lexem() const;
        virtual int yylex() override {throw std::runtime_error("Wrong Lex Called");}
        virtual int yylexWithAction();
        int yylexWithActionGo() { started = true; return yylexWithAction(); }
};

}

#endif
```

#### Lexer.cpp

```
#include "Lexer.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice;

Lexer::Lexer(std::istream& input)
    : yyFlexLexer(&input, &std::cerr)
    , started(false)
{}

std::string_view Lexer::lexem() const
{
    int length = started ? YYLeng() : 0;
    std::string_view    tokenView(YYText(), length);
    while (tokenView.size() > 0 && tokenView[tokenView.size() - 1] == '\0')
    {
        tokenView.remove_suffix(1);
    }
    return tokenView;
}
```

#### Parser.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_PARSER_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_PARSER_H

#include "exp.tab.hpp"
#include "Lexer.h"
#include "Action.h"

namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Lexer;
class Parser
{
    public:
        Parser(Lexer& lexer, Action& action);
        bool parse();
    private:
        ::yy::Parser    parser;
};

}

#endif
```

#### Parser.cpp

```
#include "Parser.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice;

Parser::Parser(Lexer& lexer, Action& action)
    : parser(lexer, action)
{}

bool Parser::parse()
{
    return parser.parse() == 0;
}
```

#### ParserUtil.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_PARSER_UTIL_H
#define THORSANVIL_ANVIL_ICE_PARSER_UTIL_H

#include "Lexer.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Action.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{
    inline void parse(std::istream& stream, Action& action)
    {
        Lexer           lexer(stream);
        Parser          parser(lexer, action);

        for (bool finished = false; !finished;)
        {
            try {
                finished = parser.parse();
            }
            catch(std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
                action.clean();
                int token;
                for(token = lexer.yylexWithAction(); token != '\n';) {
                    token = lexer.yylexWithAction();
                    if (token == yy::Parser::token::END_OF_FILE) {
                        finished = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

### An Implementation that simply does the above

#### Expression.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_APP_EXPRESSION_H
#define THORSANVIL_APP_EXPRESSION_H

#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <charconv>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Application
{

class Expression
{
    public:
        virtual ~Expression(){}
        virtual int evaluate() const = 0;
};
class BinaryExpression: public Expression
{
    Expression* lhs;
    Expression* rhs;
    public:
        BinaryExpression(Expression* lhs, Expression* rhs)
            : lhs(lhs)
            , rhs(rhs)
        {}
        int le() const {return lhs->evaluate();}
        int re() const {return rhs->evaluate();}
};

class PowerExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const { return std::pow(le(), re());}
};
class AddExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() + re();}
};
class SubExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() - re();}
};
class MulExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() * re();}
};
class DivExpression: public BinaryExpression
{
    public:
        using BinaryExpression::BinaryExpression;
        virtual int evaluate() const {return le() / re();}
};
class LiteralIntExpression: public Expression
{
    int value;
    public:
        LiteralIntExpression(std::string_view view)
            : value(0)
        {
            auto check = std::from_chars(std::begin(view), std::end(view), value);
            if (check.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Out of range");
            }
        }
        virtual int evaluate() const {return value;}
};
class IdentifierExpression: public Expression
{
    static std::map<std::string, int>   valueMap;

    std::string identifier;
    public:
        IdentifierExpression(std::string_view view)
            : identifier(view)
        {}
        virtual int evaluate() const {return valueMap[identifier];}

        static void addValue(IdentifierExpression* exp, Expression* value)
        {
            valueMap[exp->identifier] = value->evaluate();
        }
};

}

#endif
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "Action.h"
#include "ParserUtil.h"
#include "Expression.h"

using  namespace ThorsAnvil::Application;

class SimpleAction: public ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::Action
{

    template<typename T>
    Id newBinExpression(Id lhs, Id rhs)
    {
        Id result = expressions.size();
        expressions[result] = new T(expressions[lhs], expressions[rhs]);
        return result;
    }
    template<typename T>
    Id newUniExpression(std::string_view view)
    {
        Id result = expressions.size();
        expressions[result] = new T(view);
        return result;
    }
    public:
        ~SimpleAction() {clean();}
        virtual void program(Id StatementList)                                      override {clean();}
        virtual Id  statementListCreate()                                           override {return 0;}
        virtual Id  statementListAdd(Id statementList, Id statement)                override {return 0;}

        virtual Id  statementExpression(Id expression)                              override
        {
            std::cout << "Value: " << expressions[expression]->evaluate() << "\n";
            return 0;
        }
        virtual Id  statementAssignment(Id identifier, Id expression)               override
        {
            IdentifierExpression::addValue(dynamic_cast<IdentifierExpression*>(expressions[identifier]), expressions[expression]);
            return 0;
        }

        virtual Id  expression(Id addExpression)                override {return addExpression;}

        virtual Id addExpression(Id multExpression)             override {return multExpression;}
        virtual Id addExpressionAdd(Id lhs, Id rhs)             override {return newBinExpression<AddExpression>(lhs, rhs);}
        virtual Id addExpressionSub(Id lhs, Id rhs)             override {return newBinExpression<SubExpression>(lhs, rhs);}

        virtual Id multExpression(Id powerExpression)           override {return powerExpression;}
        virtual Id multExpressionMul(Id lhs, Id rhs)            override {return newBinExpression<MulExpression>(lhs, rhs);}
        virtual Id multExpressionDiv(Id lhs, Id rhs)            override {return newBinExpression<DivExpression>(lhs, rhs);}

        virtual Id powerExpression(Id primaryExpression)        override {return primaryExpression;}
        virtual Id powerExpressionPow(Id lhs, Id rhs)           override {return newBinExpression<PowerExpression>(lhs, rhs);}

        virtual Id primaryExpressionLiteral(Id literal)         override {return literal;}
        virtual Id primaryExpressionSubExpr(Id expression)      override {return expression;}
        virtual Id primaryExpressionIdent(Id identifier)        override {return identifier;}

        virtual Id literalCreate(std::string_view literal)      override {return newUniExpression<LiteralIntExpression>(literal);}
        virtual Id identifierCreate(std::string_view identifier)override {return newUniExpression<IdentifierExpression>(identifier);}

        virtual void handleError(std::string const& msg)        override {throw std::runtime_error(msg);}

        void clean() override
        {
            for (auto const& v: expressions) {
                delete v.second;
            }
            expressions.clear();
        }
    private:
        std::map<Id, Expression*>        expressions;
};

int main()
{
    SimpleAction    action;
    ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice::parse(std::cin, action);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.PHONY` target name is misspelt.  As is `$(LDFLAGS)`.

The standard name for Lex flags is `LFLAGS`.

---

`$(SRC)` seems to be used only to initialise `$(OBJ)`, so we can eliminate that:

```
OBJ  = exp.tab.o exp.lex.o Lexer.o Parser.o Expression.o main.o
```

---

If we rename `main.cpp` to `expression.cpp` we can avoid having to write a command for the linking:

```
expression: $(OBJ)
```

---

The `clean` target fails to remove `exp.tab.hpp` and `expression`.  Also `$(RM)` already includes the `-f` flag, so we can write:

```
clean::
    $(RM) expression *.o exp.???.* location.hh position.hh stack.hh
```

I use the `::` form of rule here so I can also remove editor backup files:

```
clean::
    $(RM) *~
```

---

`YACC ?= bison` doesn't have any effect on my platform, because Make's built-in rules already provide a value:

```
$ make -f /dev/null --print-data-base | grep '^YACC ='
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
YACC = yacc
```

As Bison is *required*, we should make that a `=` or `:=` rule:

```
YACC = bison
```

Unfortunately, my platform has GNU Bison 3.8.2, which dislikes the sources:

```
exp.y:2.10-15: error: invalid version requirement: 2.1a
    2 | %require "2.1a"
      |          ^~~~~~
exp.y:4.9-27: error: expected identifier before string
    4 | %define "parser_class_name" "Parser"
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It also complains about defining `YYSTYPE`.  I ended up with

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require "3.8"
%defines
%define api.parser.class {Parser}
%define api.value.type {Action::Id}
```

---

I never did get the code compiling on my Debian system, so it needs a bit more portability work before it's ready for sharing.

Comment: I'm genuinely disappointed I didn't get as far as running the code and experimenting with it.  Unfortunately, it's 25 years or more since I used Yacc and Lex, and never with C++, so I wasn't able to immediately resolve the problems.  It's something I really could learn from.

Comment: I will see if I can set up a virtual machine this weekend. Do you use a particular distribution of Debian (a link to a distro CD would be perfect).

Answer (score 1):

### Makefile

> `.PHONEY:`

This is not a special target, it should be `.PHONY` without the "E"

> `$(RM) -f $(OBJ) exp.tab.cpp exp.tab.h exp.lex.cpp exp.lex.h location.hh  position.hh stack.hh`

Inconsistencies can be distracting (extra space in `location.hh  position.hh`)

### exp.y

> `Expression:             AddExpression`

Although not an error, you could use `%left` and `%right` to set precendence